# Facebook button delegate doesn't work correctly

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, facebook-ios-sdk

I have facebook button in my viewController. I set it as:

```
var loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
loginButton.center = self.view.center
self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
```

All works, but I want to get response after when user logged in. For it I do:

```
class LogInSocialController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate
```

and call these 2 functions:

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
    print("User Logged In")
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    print("User Logged Out")
}
```

but they are do not response me and I do not get nothing in my logs(the result of prints).

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this line:

```
loginButton.delegate = self
```

And your code look like:

```
var loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
loginButton.center = self.view.center
loginButton.delegate = self
self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
```